# Please sketch the curve of parametric equation

Tags: calculus

Please, sketch the curve by using the parametric equation to plot points. 
$x=\frac{1}{e^t}+t $ and
$y=e^t-t$ where $ t \in [-2,2]$

Comment: Did you try anything? For example, first/last points, how the first coordinate looks, etc.? Have you noticed some rather peculiar relation between both coordinates *in the given interval*?

Comment: Have you noticed that $\;x(t)\;$ on $\;[-2,0]\;$  is the same as $\;y(t)\;$ on $\;[0,2]\;$ and the other way around...?

Comment: _HINT_: It looks like a V.

Comment: Use matlab ^ㅡㅡ^

Answer (score 2):

A non-standard approach:

You can see the curve as the vector sum of $(e^{-t},e^t)$ and $(t,-t)$. The first term corresponds to an arc of the equileral hyperbola $xy=1$ from $(e^{-2},e^2)$ to $(e^2,e^{-2})$.

Plot this branch and tickmark it with the values of $t$. Then from every tickmark, draw the vector $(t,-t)$, which is in the direction of the second bissector.

[image]

Around $t=0$, the equation is $(1+t^2/2+o(t^2),1+t^2/2+o(t^2))$ by Taylor, i.e. $x\approx y$. Thus the curve has a cusp, tangented by the first bissector.

---

With an extra term, $$(x,y)=(1+t^2/2-t^3/6,1+t^2/2+t^3/6).$$ If you translate to the origin and rotate by $45°$ you get $$\sqrt2(t^2/2,t^3/6),$$ a semicubic parabola.